Repurposing liion charger, understanding pinout
I have this charger built for some kind of drill.  LiIon, 12 V it says.  From shape it probably was 3 18650s in series.  Bunch of electronics inside but the part which actually contacts the battery seems simple enough except I can make no sense of the voltages I measure.
There are 5 contacts:  B+, B-,NTC, 3.6 V, 7.2 V.
B+ and B- show no voltage, though they would appear to be the meain power leads,  NTC is apparently a temperature monitor, though I don't see a thermistor.  And I get approx +5 V between the other two leads and NTC but no voltage to anything else.
Makes no sense to me.  Can anybody translate?  I'd like to repurpose this thing as general purpose charger for 19650s.
Yes, 18650's.  I'm just as bad a typist as I am  a proofreader.

Assuming that link worked, it is a picture of the contacts which contacted the battery.
There is no sign of a thermistor, so I presume it was built into the battery pack and the NTC simply picked up the signal.
What voltages did I expect?  Well, I would have expected 3.6v to something, 7.2v to something, and 10.8 v to something.  And some kind of voltage between B+ and B-.

where are you looking for the thermistor?

what voltages do you expect at each of the junctions between the three cells?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is "19650s" in the final paragraph of the question a typo? I.e. should it have been "... general purpose charger for 18650s"?
